# How to prevent the last row of a databound datagridview from being sorted on column header clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a databound datagridview. I insert a new row representing a sum of values from a specific column. The issue is I cannot prevent this row from being sorted (it should be always the last row in the grid)! Is it possible?

thx for your answers!

Comment: Well, it can be done fairly easily if your grid is not `databound`, however it depends on what kind of `DataSource` you are using for your grid, is it a `DataTable`?

Comment: Yes, it's a DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to test, but this should do the trick

```
dataGridView.Columns[dataGridView.ColumnCount - 1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

Comment: Sorry, but it should be a ROW keeping its last position after sorting, not a COLUMN.